# Axapta operator overloading

Tags: operator-overloading, axapta, x++

I was wondering if it is possible to overload the == operator in x++.

In C# I would do it like this

```
public static bool operator == (SomeObject obj1, SomeObject obj2)
{
   bool status = false;
   //Compare the objects
   return status;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator overloading is not supported.

See [this list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd261515.aspx) for other differences to C#.